# Parallel Usage of Buck Converters | LM2596 Module

Tags: buck, usb-c, usb-pd

For my application, I need three voltages +5V, +15V, -15V

Initially, I was using wall socket plugs to connect two 15 volt adaptors, in which I connected the + and - together and considered it as ground, and used that common ground connected to another wall adapter (5V)'s negative to get a common ground, and all my voltages +5V, +15V and -15V.

Since this is cumbersome, I wanted to streamline my power supply, I got a USB-C PD adaptor (capable of giving 20V), and three off the shelf module of LM2596 from amazon, along with a USB-C PD power negotiation chip (zy12pdn). However, wiring it up as mentioned above leads to a short.

Below is the circuit diagram that I am using, previously it was wall adaptors, now its buck converters, now this leads to a complete short and stops USB-C PD from working.

- Can adding diodes help the situation?
- Is there something wrong with this approach?
- How can I fix it?

[image: Here is my rough circuit diagram]

Comment: That's simply not fixable with these converters.  But there are switching converters which can generate a negative output from a positive supply.  Better yet just buy a mains supply with the outputs you need.

Comment: Ground on input and output are linked, so hard to see how you can achieve.  You need a buck-boost for negative.

Comment: I got a module off amazon https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07NTXSJHB/ based on XL6009, unfortunately, this too has a common ground. @StainlessSteelRat do you have any suggestions on how to work this out?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, if it set up for negative voltages.  Your problem was common ground, while trying to use buck as a negative source.

Comment: That will not work for you.  Positive voltages out.

Comment: This will give you +15V and -15V.  [KNACRO 20W Micro Boost Step-Down Voltage Converter DC 5-40V to DC ±15V](https://www.amazon.com/KNACRO-Step-Down-Converter-Regulator-Transformer/dp/B07Y5W1SB9/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=dc-dc+converter+negative+voltage&qid=1602626473&sr=8-5) No idea on power needs.

Comment: this looks perfect. thankyou @StainlessSteelRat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot work as on this type of buck converters, the - and the input and the - at the output are **shorted**. Let me draw those connections into your drawing:

[image]

Note how your "-15 V has a direct connection to ground.

You're also shorting (to ground) the + output of the most left converter.

Comment: Can you point out what kind of buck conveter would work in such a situation ?